# Current time is older than the previously saved time

Tags: javascript, time

My assumption is that time always runs forward, but apparently sometimes it doesn’t happen this way.

I have the following example:

```
var LOOP_MS = 100;

var prevCall = +new Date();

setTimeout(function loop() {
    foobar();

    setTimeout(loop, LOOP_MS);
}, LOOP_MS);

function foobar() {
    var now = +new Date(),
        diff = now - prevCall;  // expected to be somewhere around LOOP_MS

    // do stuff
    console.log(diff);

    prevCall = now;
}
```

Now, most of the time it works as expected, and `diff` shows a number close to 100. Of course, in the real-life scenario I’d expect the number to go up, especially when the user’s computer is performing some heavy operation.

What I don’t expect, is to see a negative number, and yet it happens. How is possible? Am I missing something? I thought maybe it could be caused by a different timezone, but it’s not. I also see it in different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), and the diff values are quite inconsistent: anything from -9, to -100 000.

It happens in about 0.025% of cases on production, so it’s not a big issue, but I’m wondering how on earth can it possibly happen (even in theory)?

I think I managed to reproduce it a couple of times locally by running the script in a slow VM and emulating high CPU load, but I still don’t see why the function would show a negative number (meaning, `now` is older than `prevCall`).

Comment: can you tell us for which input `prevCall` and `now` it is showing such behaviour?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it's a shortcut for `(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: @gurvinder372 I'm not sure I understand your question. The whole code is in the post, there's no input.

Comment: I found this interesting and set up a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cqqBBmIEMg518ZEEXuys?p=preview. I cannot reproduce your issues with negative numbers. Numbers are always 100 at minimum when running it.

Comment: Just as @Hinrich said, can't reproduce this. Maybe there's something wrong with your hardware.

Comment: I'm also not able to reproduce the issue on both browser and Node. Here's [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y4aq5cu5/) with few suggestions which _might_ solve the problem. Can you add complete code to reproduce the issue? I think the issue could be with the code that is not included.

Comment: I think a couple of the answers are on the right track.  There is some other process running on your system that is updating the system time.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it only a couple of times on a local VM in the conditions I described in the post. I this behaviour on production, it's about ~10 negative numbers for 1 000 000 calls (it varies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most computers are configured to use NTP servers to set the system clock.

As the system clock is set the first time normally it will stay in sync without need of updates.

At times (rarely) for various reasons the system clock may go out of sync.

As the system clock doesn't match with the NTP server time it is updated and may go backwards.

NTP services are (normally) configured to avoid the clock going backwards: if the "gap" is small enought the NTP daemon tries instead to "slow down" the system clock until it's again in sysnc. But as just said this depends on the configuration and the size of the time gap.

I think all the above cause in rare cases the issue you're seeing.

You may find this interesting: [Is there a way to ensure ntp synced clock never moves backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068445/is-there-a-way-to-ensure-ntp-synced-clock-never-moves-backwards)

---

If you're on macOS you may try opening the console and searching for `ntpd`.

On my machine (a MBP with 10.9.5) I see a couple of lines like this...

```
Apr  2 01:11:40 mac-di-paolo.local ntpd[46]: ntpd: wake time set -1.848017 s
```

...that logs a system clock adjustment.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to verify it, but it does sound possible.

Comment: @DanielJF I agree, because it's hard to reproduce. But there are many clues that point in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

`prevCall` is a global variable with a generic name - is it possible that some other function writes to it?

Comment: Nope, that's the only JS on the page.

Answer (score 0):

1st. You have an inaccurate equation which will at least give -1 to +1 over a delay quote even in highly accurate IE timers. So that's normal.

2nd. timers have a low priority execution and even the slightest client mouse page interaction may throw it's interval a few ms off.

All other sync operations, functions and events, will put them (timers) on halt and cause an even higher amount of disturbance of the given interval.

Comment: Well, that negative time you've experienced, might happen only on V8 machines considering that the timer functions are passed like strings they might get split in half with premature compilation than put in stack because of some halting process, and since chromes have fully "unstable sort" of hashes, the values may easily switch order when released, and there you go, you might just get a negative delta.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's quite easy to make this happen by changing the time on your computer.

It is difficult to solve this problem generically, but you may find something clever for a more specific problem. For instance, if you are showing a countdown clock on your website then your server can say what the GMT start time is, what it thinks "now" is and how many seconds remain. Whenever things "go wrong"*, you can ask your server for that same information, and given that info you can compare to what local time is on the machine. Basically, you can use the server time as a reference point rather than the frontend's time.

**Go wrong** * - By this I mean, the timer goes negative or too much time has passed since the last execution. Too much time could mean 20 seconds.

Comment: I thought about this scenario, but shouldn't the time zone change if the function is getting a high negative value? Because it doesn't happen.